# How to perform calculation in values of dictionary

Tags: python

**Task:**
Calculate q1_weight/q1value and store that in q1_normalize. How can i do this?

**Dataset**
Items   q1_weight   q1_value   Manufacturer
I1          30                21             M1
I2          39                25             M2

**Code:**

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
data=[]
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook('Data.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
worksheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
num_rows=worksheet.nrows
num_cols=worksheet.ncols
#======================================================================
Printing all the values of excel sheet
for row_index in range(0,num_rows):
    print('-'*40)
    print   ('Row: %s' % row_index)
    for col_index in range(0,num_cols):
        cell_obj=worksheet.cell(row_index,col_index)
        print('Column: [%s] Cell_oj: [%s]' % (col_index,cell_obj))
print("+"*100)
#=======================================================================

keys = [worksheet.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in range(worksheet.ncols)]
dict_list = []
for row_index in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    d = {keys[col_index]: worksheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
         for col_index in range(worksheet.ncols)}
    dict_list.append(d)
Manufact=raw_input("Enter Manufacturer name: ")
string=Manufact.title()
temp=next(item for item in dict_list if item["Manufacturer"] == string)

ordered_list=["Items","q1_weight","q1_value","q1_normalize","q2_weight","q2_value", "q2_normalize","q3_weight","q3_value","q3_normalize","q4_weight","q4_value","q4_normalize", "q5_weight","q5_value","q5_normalize","Manufacturer"]
# for row_index in range(0):
#     d = {keys[col_index]: worksheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
#          for col_index in range(worksheet.ncols)}
#     h.append(d)
# print(h)
wb=Workbook("Result.xlsx")
ws=wb.add_worksheet("New Sheet")

first_row=0
for header in ordered_list:
    col=ordered_list.index(header) # we are keeping order.
    ws.write(first_row,col,header) # we have written first row which is the header of worksheet also.

row=1
for _key,_value in temp.items():
    col=ordered_list.index(_key)
    ws.write(row,col,_value)
row+=1 #enter the next row
wb.close()
```

**Output of code**

```
{u'q1_weight': 30.0, u'Items': u'I1', u'q1_normalize': u'', u'q1_value': 21.0, u'Manufacturer': u'M1'}
```

**Example output**

```
 {u'q1_weight': 30.0, u'Items': u'I1', u'q1_normalize': u'1.42', u'q1_value': 21.0, u'Manufacturer': u'M1'}
```

Comment: This could easily be tl;dr down to an example dictionary like so: `{'q1_weight' : 30, 'q1_value' : 21, 'test' : 'M1'}` and then show us an example output as: `{'q1_normalize' : 26, 'q1_weight' : 30...}`. We really don't need all the XML, XLS w/e code here. It just makes it harder to focus on your task at hand :) Try to keep your questions short but with enough context and content to give us something to work with. Welcome to SO and best of luck with your question.

Comment: But also this sounds like a question from a school book and that to me doesn't sit right. If that's the case I'm voting to close this unless there's actual problems with your code that you're stuck with.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't just post your homework instructions and dump a bunch of irrelevant code.

Comment: let a is the output then a['q1_normalize'] = a['q1_weight']/a['q1value']

Comment: Sure, I will edit my question

Comment: Edited the question, Please help me